# search gridview with objectdatasource

Tags: asp.net

I have this procedure for performing the search:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.book_serchbook
   @BookTitle nvarchar(100) ,
   @CategoryName nvarchar (100) ,
   @AuthorName nvarchar(100),
   @PublisherName nvarchar(100) 
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT 
       dbo.BookTable.BookID,
       dbo.BookTable.BookCover,
       dbo.BookTable.BookPrice,
       dbo.BookTable.BookTitle,
       dbo.PublisherTable.PublisherName,
       dbo.CategoryTable.CategoryName
    FROM          
       BookTable 
    INNER JOIN
       CategoryTable ON CategoryTable.CategoryID = BookTable.CategoryID
    INNER JOIN 
       PublisherTable ON PublisherTable.PublisherID = BookTable.PublisherID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
       BookAuthorTable 
    INNER JOIN 
       AuthorTable ON AuthorTable.AuthorID = BookAuthorTable.AuthorID 
       ON BookTable.BookID = BookAuthorTable.BookID
    WHERE     
       (PublisherTable.PublisherName LIKE '%' + @PublisherName + '%') and
       (BookTable.BookTitle LIKE '%' + @BookTitle + '%') and
       (AuthorTable.AuthorFName + ' ' + AuthorTable.AuthorLName LIKE '%' + @AuthorName + '%') and
       (CategoryTable.CategoryName= @CategoryName )
```

On my ASPX page I use a gridview with `ObjectDataSource` to display results, the object source code Is :

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource4" runat="server" 
     DataObjectTypeName="BookDataBaseComponent.BookDetails"  OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
     DeleteMethod="DeleteBook" InsertMethod="InsertBook" SelectMethod="SearchBook" 
     TypeName="BookDataBaseComponent.BookDB" UpdateMethod="UpdateBook">
     <DeleteParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="BookID" Type="Int32" />
     </DeleteParameters>
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="booktb" DefaultValue="%" Name="BookTitle" 
             PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" DefaultValue="%" 
             Name="CategoryName" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="afnbk" DefaultValue="%" Name="AuthorName" 
             PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="pubtb" DefaultValue="%" Name="PublisherName" 
             PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
     </SelectParameters>
 </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

My problem: the page doesn't display any results while the and operator between conditions in the `where` clause is present. When I change it to `OR` it displays results

And I can't search when I click the search button nothing happens.

Please any help .I really need help

Comment: Have you tried to **test** it without the grid-view by putting the values into the stored-procedure straight away ?

Comment: I try to test it ,in result show me the book but in return value it show 0